# Could not find 'json' (>= 1.5.1) among 46 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Tags: json, react-native, rubygems, gemspecs

iam unable to install the pods in this project
cd ios
pod install
this error shows
Please help if you have any fix

[image]

pods should install

Comment: can you post the output of `gem env`, and your Podfile. Maybe try `pod install` first instead

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ruby path is not set correctly in the M1 chip environment and can be resolved by the following steps

```
1、rvm list
2、rvm use ruby-3.0.0 --default
3、pod install
```

Solve the problem

[image]